# handling get urls in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a message that shows up when `login.php?e=1` on the login page: `/login/`. The issue I am coming to have is that in codeigniter when I do `/login/e/1/` codeigniter seems to think `e` is a function and thus, since it doesnt exist, outputs a `404`.
I am trying, in the index function to grab the segments like a get request, however this does not work. How can one do typical get requests that would be trivial outside of codeigniter, in codeigniter while staying true to the uri that codeigniter uses?

```
    // Are they attempting to access a secure page?
    if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'e' && $this->uri->segment(2) == '1'):
        if ($this->generic->getOption('block-msg-out-enable')) {
            $this->msg = $this->generic->getOption('block-msg-out');
        }
    endif;
```

Comment: you need to use `_remap()`, I'll show you how in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is nothing to show just hit this [link](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/controllers.html?highlight=remap#remapping-method-calls).

If you are lazy then watch it here.

`_remap` function overrides `index()` (or any other declared function in a controller), in a way

```
function _remap($method, $params) {

    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {

        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);

    } else {

        array_unshift($params, $method);
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, "index"), $params);

    }

}
```

//after 1st comment take a look here

```
function _remap($method, $params) { //this is "kind" of your new index(); but it takes parameters

    if ($method == 'e') {

        echo $params[0];

    } else {

        show_404();

    }

}
```

Comment: i am still confused as to how i should access `?e=1` or `/e/1`

Comment: please, try this `http://localhost/project/login/index/e/1` if that works you also need to edit routes.php to something like `$route['login/(:any)/(:any)'] = "login/index/$1/$2";` but hey `_remap()` is your new `index()` that takes 2 params (1st is always method, 2nd is array of parameters) so if you have no other methods in that controller just use _remap()

Comment: easiest way for me was to enable query strings and do it `/login/?e=1` but this answers my question

Comment: It's good you wrote the explanation here for us "lazy" people instead of just referring to the link because the link you posted is dead.  The new link is https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls

Comment: @DavidRhoderick I dont think you should be using CodeIgniter anymore.

Comment: Actually the new link is at https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/controllers.html?highlight=remap#remapping-method-calls @Kyslik we all don't get to choose what frameworks we are handed to work with

Comment: @Kyslik I didn't realize I could suggest an edit to your answer; there's the latest documentation link