# How to get CodeIgniter to ignore the last segment entered into the URL-but still keep it there?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I'm using CodeIgniter to build a user profile section from scratch. What happens is, the user will put in the URL:

```
www.somesite.com/profile/view/<USERNAME>
```

(**profile** is the folder & **view** is the controller)

and I will use IF ELSE statements to check to see if **$currentURL** (see below) is in the DB and load the required page.

But what's happening right now is it's looking for a function(I think) inside **view** to execute. But there is none. Which results in a 404 error.

Is it possible for CodeIgniter to ignore the last segment of that URL but still keep it there so that I can use;

```
$currentURL = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

to grab the **USERNAME**?

Thanks for viewing my question,

Lewis.

Comment: CI only uses what you tell it to, by having a long URL you pick what URI segments you want. You could make fancy URLs and only use half the data and ignore the rest (ex: `/view/(postid)/(posttitle)`)

Comment: @EHU-Lewis are you getting 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

<strike>declare your function as follows</strike>

`public function view($var1, $username = "") {...}`

where `$var1` must be filled in but `$username` can be ommited and its default value is `""`

---

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class View extends CI_Controller { //can not belive that View is not reserved word

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        //index() function can not have parameters
        //redirect('view/show');
        //if no username is set, do default thing like show list of users
        //load view or something
    }

    public function show($username = "") {
        //this function can have parameters
        //load views from here
        $this->load->view('abc_view');
    }
}
```

Add to routes.php following

`$route['profile/view/(:any)'] = "profile/view/show/$1";`

this will allow you to have nice URL as you expect

`site.com/profile/view/Peterson123`

**NOTE** when using "routing" method do not `redirect(profile/view/show)` in `index()`

---

**Another aproach** that uses `_remap()` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686593/1564365).

Comment: not the right way, you want to use `$this->uri->segment()` a CI class to properly test for values and eliminate missing vars. What you post will work in vanilla PHP, but CI is a framework.

Comment: @Jakub I think OP can not get thru 404 error, which means he is calling a controller without parameter. Which is odd because of OPs site structure `www.somesite.com/profile/view/<USERNAME>` I assume `profile` is folder and `view` is controller. Therefore he is missing every "<username>" method in view controller (404 error).

Comment: Hi, sorry i'll clear some things up (and then edit my post).
Yes, profile is the folder, view would be the controller and view would be the function within the controller. So when I put **tim** as the username in the URL  it just says page not found.

Comment: @Jakub OP is looking for _remap() as he stated that he is getting 404.

Comment: @Kyslik redirect('view/show') instead of $this->load->view('...') ?

Comment: @EHU-Lewis please note that `index()` method can not have parameters, see my edits and linked answer. So whatever you had in `index()` move it to newly created function `show()` and access everything from that function.

Comment: @Kyslik Okay. Let me start off by saying I only started CodeIgniter the last couple of weeks and this stuff is confusing as hell.

I've added the route php into routes.php

What exactly do you mean by "redirect('view/show');" within index()?

Comment: @EHU-Lewis, whenever you access your controller by `site.com/profile/view/` `index()` method (**function**) is called FIRST or right away, unfortunately `index()` does not accept any parameters (we are talking about <USERNAME>). So what you need to do is whenever is `site.com/profile/view` called either redirect it to `site.com/profile/view/show`, where `show()` function can take parameters (like `$username` eg. `site.com/profile/view/show/pete123`) or have routes.php take care of it. Problem is whenever there is no <username> you have to take care of it explicitly.

Comment: @Kyslik Wow dude. You are a god among men. Thank you so much for this! It worked. Got it to store the $username as session data and then display it on the next page to see if it worked and it did. I can't thank you enough for all your help!

Comment: @EHU-Lewis Yet, I made another edit! Please let yourself think about what happens when view is called without parameter.

Comment: @Kyslik That's a good thing to think about. I did have an idea of showing a custom error page just saying that that user doesn't exist or something.

Comment: Good, load that (error page) view file in `index()` function and you are done.

Comment: @Kyslik thanks for all your help. I don't think i'd have ever got there on my own. Didn't really want to ask on here but time was ticking away and this was a last resort.

Comment: If it was `/profile/view/<USERNAME>` then profile would be CONTROLLER, VIEW be fn in that controller class, and username would be segment 3... the question was formatted very poorly.

Comment: @Jakub Yes it was, at first I understood it exactly same way as you did but this `is it's looking for a function` made it clear.