# how to Redirect if slug was incorrect in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to redirect slug that was incorrect but I am getting error with URL is not detected.

This is my controller:

```
    public function index($id = null, $slug = ''){
// Fetch the article
        //$this->db->where('pubdate <=', date('Y-m-d'));
        $this->data['article'] = $this->mberita->get_by_id($id,$slug);
       // Return 404 if not found
        count($this->data['article']) || show_404(uri_string());

        // Redirect if slug was incorrect
        $requested_slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $set_slug = $this->data['article']->slug;
        if ($requested_slug != $set_slug) {
            redirect('article/' . $this->data['article']->id . '/' . url_title($set_slug), 'location', '301');


        // Load view
        $this->data['contents'] = 'article';
        $this->load->view('template/wrapper/mahasiswa/wrapper_article', $this->data);

    }
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="post-buttons">
       <a href="<?php echo 'article/' . intval($dt->id) . '/' . url_title($dt->slug) ; ?>" class="ui black label">
             Read More
       </a>
 </div>
```

I try this url:

```
tkd/index.php/article/77/kejurnas-mahasiswa
```

but URL is not detected. can you help me what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your .htaccess file.

Comment: .htaccess file is "Deny from all" how?

Comment: @RPM OP is not using any `.htacces` file yet, OP still has "index.php" in the URLs. Contents of `.htaccess` above `Deny from all` is in application folder that has nothing to do with OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality.  Please update it with pertinent information to make it of more value.

Answer (score 0):

I read your posts all day long about your magic slugs, nothing against them but hey why do you want to have any slugs at all when you have ID in your URL?

First of all CodeIgniters `index()` function does not take any parameters, you need to create pseudo index page + edit routes.php (I will explain later in answer) or [_remap()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) your controller. If you want to use `_remap()` I briefly explain it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686593/1564365).

*instead using index "parameters" use uri segments* (as you are doing already by `$this->uri->segment(n)`)

---

Lets get back to the point where you are using slugs, I understand that you are simply trying to get following: `site.ufo/article/{id}/whatever-text-can-be-here-id-is-important`

To achieve this behavior, make this route in your `routes.php`

```
$route['article/(:num)/(:any)'] = "article/show_article/$1/$2"; //where article is controller and show_article is "behind the scene" method that takes over your index(); not a single user will know about it
```

Now lets make some changes in your class named article.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Article extends CI_Controller { 
//I can spot that you are extending your controller NOT by CI_Controller because of usage $this->data[]

    public function __construct() {
        //constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('article_model', 'article'); //load model article_model and create alias "article"

    }

    public function index() {
        //let this be empty or redirect if no ID is sent to the controller
        redirect(); //redirect to default_controller  
    }

    public function show_article($id = FALSE, $slug = FALSE) {
        if ($id === FALSE) redirect(); // no id? redirect to default_controller
        if ($slug === FALSE) {
            //slug is not sent to the article
            //you should do nothing if this happens but you may require reload page with correct slug
                //get slug by id
                //redirect(/article/$id/slug_by_id)
        }

        // Fetch the article
        //$this->db->where('pubdate <=', date('Y-m-d'));
        if ($this->data['article'] = $this->article->get($id)) {
            //all good we can show result
            $this->data['contents'] = 'article';
            $this->load->view('template/wrapper/mahasiswa/wrapper_article', $this->data);

        } else {
            //get() method returns FALSE
            redirect(); //id is not valid or there is no such record with id = $id
        }

    }

}

/* End of file article.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/article.php */
```

lastly create file (model) `application/models/article_model.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Article extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //Do your magic here
    }

    public function get( $id = FALSE ) {
        if ($id === FALSE) return FALSE;

        $q = $this->db->get_where('article', array('id' => $id)); // table = 'article'

        return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result() : FALSE;

    }


}

/* End of file article_model.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/article_model.php */
```